# Ubuntu "unavailable" after install

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, dell

I'm installing Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.2 on a Dell T320.  It has a H310 PERC that has been flashed to it. The PERC is recognized in the installation, and the installation seems to run through without issue.  I'm not receiving any errors. After the installation, the system reboots, and it cannot boot into the OS.  In Legacy BIOS, it says "No Bootable Disks Available" and UEFI shows "Unavailable: ubuntu".

I have tried installing multiple times with either Legacy or UEFI. I have multiple flash drives, and the result is the same across the board. This is *not* a dual boot system. It is being set up as the sole OS. I was initially trying to install Ubuntu 23.04 live Server, and ran into similar issues. The installation seems to complete without a hitch, but after it reboots it will not boot to the OS. I'm going to stick with Ubuntu desktop at this point, as I've spent nearly 2 weeks on each already. And Desktop is what I've currently got on my flash drives.

I've used both 2.0 & 3.0 USB drives. I've flashed with PowerISO, Rufus, UNetbootin, Universal USB, and others. Again it seems to go through the install perfectly fine. It's after the installation when I run into the problem. I've downloaded the file multiple times. I just don't know where to go from this point. Something will not allow it to boot, after installation CPU 2.2GHz Xeon, 12GB RAM, 500GB HDD (primary).

BIOS UEFI screen:

[image: BIOS UEFI Page]

Boot fail:

[image]

System info:

[image: System Info]

Comment: is your BIOS up to date?

Comment: Sorry I got confused with your details; you mention both 22.04 & 23.04, Desktop & Server.. but not which of each product/release you tried. Ubuntu 23.04 for example is available with 3 installers selected by ISO, one for Server, two for Desktop - but which you used is unknown; you mention many downloads (was this the various ISOs or repeats of the same??) etc.

Comment: correct.  multiple downloads of each as well as versions.  I was thinking maybe a version might have an issue where another might not.  I also am using multiple different USB drives.  I have San disk cruzers, kingston flash, usb with micro SD card adapters, etc.  I was thinking it might be hardware related, but I tried it on a T330, and another T320 with same results.  I truly feel there is a setting or something in the process I'm missing.

I agree that it seems confusing, so I am narrowing it down to just using 22.04.2 Desktop AMD64, at this point.  This should make troubleshooting easier.

Comment: Yes, the BIOS is up to date.  The Lifecycle firmware is also up to date.  I think I have an undesirable work around, though.  It recognizes the PERC before and after, as well as the drives, but it fails the installation every time.  There is a single available internal SATA port (2x if you count the one the optical drive is connected to).  I was able to install Ubuntu on That internal SATA connection.  I'm not happy with that setup, but I guess it'll have to work, unless someone can give me advice on what is preventing me from being able to install it with the normal setup.